# I have written this code, but this code gives error in alert dialog and the error is undefined constructor

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-alertdialog, builder

i have written this code, but this code gives error in alert dialog. The error is undefined constructor.

```
public class Age extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
    public Age(){}
   TableRow tr1,tr2,tr3,tr4,tr5,tr6,tr7,tr8,tr9,tr10,tr11;
  AlertDialog builder;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. activity_age, container, false);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Age.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT).create();
        tr2=(TableRow)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
         tr3=(TableRow)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);
         tr2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.mercury);
                    builder.setTitle("About Mercury"); builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                     builder.setMessage("Orbit: 57,910,000 km (0.38 AU) from Sun\ndiameter: 4,880 km\nmass: 3.30e23 kg\nGravity : 0.378");
                     builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {}});builder.show();}});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this line

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Age.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT).create();
```

with

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT).create();
```